# Committing a € euro sign via subversion

Tags: svn, encoding, character-encoding, euro

I am experiencing an issue with the committing a Euro symbol (€) through subversion.

When I execute the following command:

`svn diff CRMPicco.inc.php`

I see this:

```
-                '&euro;'    => '&#8364;',   // â¬ - Euro
+                'â¬'         => '&#8364;',   // â¬ - Euro
```

(`&euro;` has been removed and replaced with `€`)

I would imagine I should be able to commit a Euro symbol through subversion. Will this fil;e actually be committed as seen above or will it be €?

Comment: It looks like you've got a text encoding issue - probably the editor you used to modify the file read it in as one encoding then wrote it back out again as UTF-8. You should probably try to use UTF-8 throughout but you'll need to make sure everything in your system is expecting it! I don't think this is an svn issue - I think it's your editor.

Comment: Sure - it's just you need to be clear what "correctly" means here: UTF-8 or your code-page (CP1252? Latin-1?), and make sure that PHP and your database are using the same encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.1.

I would like to follow this up by saying that when I actually committed the code and looked at what code was actually committed the Euro symbol was correctly sent to the SVN server.